# Follow path question with offset

Tags: animation

This is what i have so far. I want to duplicate another 9 objects that are evenly spaced around the path and then move them all together by turning the empty. I don't know how to offset the other objects and for them to follow the path.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "turning the empty", what is your empty supposed to do? You don't give enough details. To offset an object on the path you just need to use the Follow Path Offset value

Comment: So i want to have 9 other objects spaced evenly around the path with the empty as the parent to all objects. I then want to change the rotation of the empty to make all the children move around the path. does make sense?